# name attribute on exception strategy is only allowed on global exception strategies

Tags: mule

I created a global exception strategy as below,

```
 <choice-exception-strategy name="GlobalExceptionStrategy">
      <catch-exception-strategy name="400:BadRequest" when="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']==&quot;400&quot;]" doc:name="400:BadRequest">
            <logger message="Caught error with code #[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]  and reason #[message.inboundProperties['http.reason']] for query payload  #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

But why I am still getting the error like name attribute is required only on global exception strategy?

Comment: can you be more specific? There's nothing wrong in that code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Error was in this line `<catch-exception-strategy **name**="400:BadRequest" when="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']==&quot;400&quot;]" doc:name="400:BadRequest">`

Using doc:name in place of name works perfect!

Comment: name is typically only required on global elements so that it can be reused and referenced by name. doc:name is just for info.